# Calling a function next to another function javascript explanation

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, rxjs

Can someone please explain to me this bit of code

```
return pipe(...fns)(this);
```

I understand if we didn't have (this), so we returned the reduced functions but `(this)` confused me.

Full source code here. line 72
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-hv4ntb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same as this:

```
const pipeFunction = pipe(...fns); // pipe returns a function
const result = pipeFunction(this); // call the returned function with this as argument
return result;                     // return the result
```

So if you ever see something like `variable(...)(...)` you should assume that the variable evaluates to a function that returns a function, like this perhaps:

```
const variable = (a) => (b) => a + b;
variable(4)(2); 
// ==> 6

const partial = variable(8)
[1, 2, 3].map(partial); 
// ==> [9, 10, 11]
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is said to have *`first-class functions`* (you can read more here on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/First-class_Function)), meaning that you can do with functions what you can do with other types. Storing them into a variable, passing them as argument to other functions, **as well as using them as return value from other functions**.

> The thinking is, just think of functions as values.

In your use-case, a function is just being returned from another function:

```js
function multiply(times) {

  return function(number) {
    return number * times;
  };
}

// as you can see, we are storing the "returned function"
// resulted from calling `multiply` into the `double` variable.
const double = multiply(2);

console.log(
  double(5)
);
```

Now, of course, you could short-circuit the `double` variable,
and just call the returned function straight away.

```js
function multiply(times) {

  return function(number) {
    return number * times;
  };
}

console.log(
  multiply(2)(5)
);
```